# Gridster on_overlap_stop override

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, grid

I'm using a jquery plugin called Gridster.

http://gridster.net/

When initializing my grid I'm trying to set a callback for `collision.on_overlap_stop` however everytime I set it the program throws all kinds of errors in the gridster code.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gridster;

  $(function(){

    gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
        draggable: {
            stop: function(event, ui)
            {
                 //code...
            }
        },
        collision:
        {
            //this function doesn't seem to be called and when this function is set the page crashes.
            on_overlap_stop: function(collider_data)
            {
                 //code....
            }
        },
    }).data('gridster');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue. If you want to use the `on_overlap_stop` or `on_overlap_start`, you need to supply them both. That way no errors are shown.